# How do you dynamically load a .net module?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I have a 2 C# libraries that I can dynamically load in VC++ after making them COM-visible and registering the DLLs into the Global Assembly Cache. Both libraries extend a common interface `MyLibrary_Common.Test` so they can be loaded by ProgId or CLSID wrapped under the common interface.

```
#import "MyLibrary.Common.tlb"
#using <mscorlib.dll>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyLibrary_Common.ITestPtr test = MyLibrary_Common.ITestPtr(argv[1]);
    printf("Lib: %s", test->getVersion());
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I were to make modules instead of COM assemblies. How would I dynamically load the modules? I'm left with 2 .netmodule files `MyLibrary.First.netmodule` and `MyLibrary.Second.netmodule`. I understand that the modules can be used through `#using` declaration but that's not dynamic.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  A .netmodule is the rough equivalent to a .lib file in native C++.  It has to be linked into an assembly before you can execute its code.

Comment: @HansPassant I wish you would make that an answer if it is. I was wondering if there is a way to load it using some kind of `LoadModule` function. I couldn't find enough information from MSDN.

Comment: Good blog on how to use .NET modules from Visual C++. https://www.mode19.net/posts/clrhostingright/